# Change Mac menu bar color to black when caps lock is on?

Tags: macos, applescript

Is it possible, and if so can anybody help me implement this?
I would like to have the mac menu bar change color, background to black with white text, when I have caps lock on?
It's a bit much for such little payoff but I think it'd be cool feature.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548327/checking-state-of-caps-lock-in-cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search, you will find that there are already various applications that do this thing (ok, not by pressing the *caps lock*, but you may use their source code - when provided - and do your own version looking at the link posted by *whiskeyspider*).

Please, note that those application simply **invert** the colors using built-in OS X features.
Doing it in other ways imply that you must edit the *ArtFile* and the *SArtFile* in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources`

I use an app of the first type; it took a bit on startup to invert the colors, but it looks great.